# how to solve design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate the model below and end up with the error that follows:

```
 mROBOT_APPRAISAL <- polr(robot_appraisal ~ genderf + up_to_15 + still_studying
                + self_employed + manager + other_whiteC 
                + manual + house_person + unempl + retired,
                 Hess = TRUE,  na.action = na.exclude )
Warning message:
In polr(robot_appraisal ~ genderf + up_to_15 + still_studying +  :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs
```

I want all the variables to be considered in summary(), what should I do?

Comment: The fit does not uniquely determine the coefficients so you can't have them all.

Comment: Is there any other way to get all the variables? Perphaps I should use another code for the ordereder logit regression?

Comment: what does rank-deficient mean?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: should i use another code to have all the coefficient for the ordinal logit regression?